# Android, Loading animation in dialog for unlimited time as blinker?

Tags: android, animation, customdialog

I have created a dialog and I want to show a text with an animation. In Progress Dialog we have a text "Loading. Please Wait..." and an image which is rotating as long as dialog is alive. My dialog is something like this but I have just one textView in this dialog and I want as long as this dialog is alive, dialog automatically enable and disable textView in each seconds (blinking text).

I think one way is using Threads and Timing but for this simple stupid situation I don't want to use it. I have created "animloading.xml" in "res/anim/" with these codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0 "
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2500" >
    </alpha>   

</set>
```

and in code, I have written:

```
final TextView tvLoading = (TextView) dialogLoading.findViewById(R.id.tvLoading);
        Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animloading);
        tvLoading.startAnimation(fade1);
```

but the problem is for first time I see my effect and after that it stops (it's clear because i don't have any looping codes). Now, the question is how can I put above codes in loop to show and repeat animation as long as this dialog is active?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Android Countdown Timer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

it has an function to check at each increment, and it has function call when timer runs out.